# Best options to highlight Geogebra syntax

Tags: minted, geogebra

I want to write something about [geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) in LaTeX. I usually use the `minted` package for listings. Is there any language supported by `minted` which which is very close to the Geogebra Syntax (as used in the geogebra command line)?

Comment: Do you have any example files and/or attempt? You can lookup minted's/pygmentize's lexers, but I don't think there is one for that.